# Change Flutter PopupMenu size

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, popupmenu

I have a nav bar on a Flutter web app which I am using PopupMenuButton for the menu. I have been able to make the menu smaller by wrapping the PopupMenuItem's child in a Container with a set width, but have not seen the same result when I try to make the Container bigger.

```
PopupMenuButton(
  itemBuilder: (context) => [
    for (Map item in menuItems)
      PopupMenuItem(child: menuItem(item))
    ],
```

SMALL CONTAINER

The code

```
Widget menuItem(data) {
  return Container(
    width: 100,
    child: Column(...)
  );
}
```

The result
[image]

LARGE CONTAINER

The code

```
Widget menuItem(data) {
  return Container(
    width: 900,
    child: Column(...)
  );
}
```

The result
[image]

NO CONTAINER

The code

```
Widget menuItem(data) {
  return Column(...)
}
```

The result
[image]

I want the menu to be as large as possible.
PS - menuItems is a list of maps with String and Icons

Comment: `width: double.infinity` for container works for you?

Comment: @SimonSot nope. With Container(width: double.infinity) I get the same result as no container or Container(width: 900)

Comment: It seems like a known issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64918

Answer (score 0):

this is currently same situation that i'm facing on. So the idea is wrapping the item with a Container which has width with Media Query like this.

```
PopupMenuItem(
  child: Container(
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
```